# Oracle Database 11G R2 iniciar serviço

Tags: oracle

Como eu inicio o serviço do banco de dados Oracle?
Instalei na máquina a versão 11G R2 para DESKTOP no Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duque,
Geralmente após a instalação do Oracle um serviço é criado no Windows, com o nome da instância que você definiu na instalação.

Para verificar, abra a console do Windows e digite:

```
            services.msc
```

Isto irá abrir o MMC (Microsoft Management Console) com todos os serviços existentes na sua máquina. A partir daí é só encontrar e iniciar o serviço do Oracle.

Espero que isto resolva seu problema. Abraços,

Comment: O serviço já estava iniciado e eu tentando encontrar onde deveria iniciar o mesmo.
Obrigado Dias.